# Ping "requested timed out" when pinging one box to other in hypervisior internal network

Tags: windows-7, networking, centos, ping

I am running a windows 7 box and centos box on hypervisior connected to a hyperV switch with internal network configuration. The subnet for them is 192.168.0.0/24 .
The windows 7 has another nic connected to physical nic. Thus through windows box I can connect to Internet.

In my setup I have to remote desktop the windows 7 box and from there go to internal network.

I am trying to ping centos box from windows' and vice-versa but "getting requested timed out". Already added the persistent route for the subnet 192.168.0.0/24 on the routing table of windows box and centos box.

Comment: Tried turning off firewall temporarily on both ends?

Comment: Yeah firewall's are off on both sides